# QuickBlox Issues

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios5, quickblox

I have been trying to implement a simple chat module within my iOS app based on the sample provided by QuickBlox site.

see/download here:>> http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios

The issue i am having is that the table that should load the users and rooms is not loading any content.

I have revised my code and look exactly like the one provided on sample (i basically export their classes) and my connections to the .h file are correct based on
the sample provide on the site.

The only different to your sample is that i am using story board and arc.

Beside this problem, everything else runs correctly. There are only to warnings that are also on the original sample, which i discard to be the cause of why my table is not loading.

I've had look for a solution on the web, but the documentation is limit for this problem.

Does any one know another approach to implement a simple chat room within your app???

any idea or suggestion will  be highly appreciated..

EDIT
use the link below to download a simple xcode project that illustrate the issue stated above..hope someone can find what i have been missing

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/20030125/QBChatTest.zip

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found what the problem is. You create session, but after that, you don't call query that retrieves all users.

So, add to class MainViewController.m, to method - (void)completedWithResult:(Result *)result
next lines of code:

```
- (void)completedWithResult:(Result *)result
{
    if([result isKindOfClass:[QBAAuthSessionCreationResult class]]){
        if (result.success)
        {
            [self qbApplicationDidAuth];
        }
    }

...
```

And, after that, you will see http://qblx.co/SRXgmJ

Comment: Hi Igor...This solve the problem mentioned on the title but still the application do not behave as the sample provide on the site...Did you tried to run the example after place this code?...i now getting the user on my table but can see who is online and either the previous chat room created..(i run the test on two computers)...also if i place in my credentials i get  index 3 beyond bounds [0 .. 2] after QBChatService/xmppStreamDidAuthenticate ..if you try it on the example i provided, it will give you all the issues i just mentioned..Thanks a lot..I really need to solve this

Comment: Also, user list display duplicate data. Each time `updateuser` method called it appends objects to `self.users` and it display duplicate data.